# PHP Ampersand in String

Tags: php, string, echo

I'm having a bit of a problem. I am trying to create an IRC bot, which has an ampersand in its password. However, I'm having trouble putting the ampersand in a string. For example...

```
<?php

$var = "g&abc123";

echo $var;

?>
```

I believe this should print `g&abc123`. However it's printing `g`.

I have tried this as well:

```
<?php
$arr = array("key" => "g&abc123");
print_r($arr);
?>
```

This prints it correctly with the `g&abc123`, however when I say `echo $arr['key'];` it prints `g` again. Any help would be appreciated. I'm running PHP5.3.1.

**EDIT**: Also, I just noticed that if I use `g&abc123&abc123` it prints `g&abc123`. Any suggestions?

Comment: I tested on PHP 5.2.9 and it works fine....now this is an odd one.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't have that issue in a console:

```
php > $d="g&abc123";
php > echo $d;
g&abc123
```

What environment are you printing the output to? It sounds like you are viewing it in a web browser, and the & is being interpreted as a malformed HTML entity. Try replacing the & symbol with the entity encoded version `&amp;`.

Comment: You are correct, I'm printing to the browser. However, it is not part of an HTML tag, link, etc. It is just the only text on the page. Also, I tried with &amp; and it DID display correctly. Unfortunately, this is a problem because I need to send the data to a server, and I'm not sure if it's being sent as g&abc123 or if it's being sent as g, and I can't send g&amp;abc123.

Comment: You can automatically transform text into this form with the PHP htmlentities function, and decode with html_entity_deocode - see http://php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php If you're sending it somewhere, etc. you can be confident the value sent is the value as shown by print_r.

Comment: You're right. I tried this in Firefox and it doesn't happen. It seems to be a Chrome problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Look at the source code, it will be printing the correct code.

If you want it to print out correctly in HTML, then run htmlentities on it or make the & `&amp;`

Comment: Then something is wrong with your server -- I just tested it (copied and pasted your code): http://www.phoenixdev.net/test-2.php

Comment: No Kerry, in Chrome I get the same results. ;) Doesn't happen in Firefox though.

Comment: Ah, that means its browser related. I tested IE6, 7 & 8 and they are all fine.

Comment: Also, if you do as I said, and put the `&amp;` it displays correct (not in the source) in Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

View the web page source to make sure your variable contains the correct value.

Answer (score 1):

You're probably sending your output to a Web browser.

The correct way of doing it is

In HTML, XHTML and XML, the ampersand has a special meaning. It is used for character entities. You can think of it as an escape sequence of sorts.

For instance, in PHP, this would be illegal:

```
$variable = 'It's Friday';
```

This is because the apostrophe is interpreted by PHP as the end of your string, and the rest of your content looks like garbage.

Instead, you have to say:

```
$variable = 'It\'s Friday';
```

Similarly, in HTML and XHTML, you can't say

```
<h1>Inequalities</h1>
<p> x<yz+3 </p>
```

This is because it would be interpreted as an element.

Instead, you'd have to say:

```
<h1>Inequalities</h1>
<p> x&lt;yz+3 </p>
```

Now, as you can see, the ampersand itself has a special meaning and, therefore, needs to be escaped as &. htmlspecialchars() will do it for you.

Comment: Well... I know the PHP examples... I also know that & has no problem in Firefox. I understand that in XHTML (and probably HTML too) &amp; is the correct way to do it. But I've never had a browser get angry because it wasn't done that way. Trust me, if I was trying to make this valid XHTML, it'd be an &, but I was just using it for debug purposes.

Comment: Unfortunately, browsers were designed to accept just about anything you throw at them, but how it's handled is subject to interpretation. The HTML5 team is trying to create a standard for the handling of "tag soup"... I'm personally not too happy about that, but what can I do? I recommend that you create an alias for echo htmlspecialchars($text); Example: function h($text) { echo htmlspecialchars($text); }